# How to add a new dimension to a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

In NumPy, I would do

```py
a = np.zeros((4, 5, 6))
a = a[:, :, np.newaxis, :]
assert a.shape == (4, 5, 1, 6)
```

How to do the same in PyTorch?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
a = torch.zeros(4, 5, 6)
a = a[:, :, None, :]
assert a.shape == (4, 5, 1, 6)
```

Comment: And for what it's worth `np.newaxis` is just `None`, anyway.

Comment: @FrankYellin I actually didn't know it also works in numpy

Comment: In situations where you don't have to do any indexing on other axes when requiring this operation, I don't see this being very useful. In my opinion `a.unsqueeze(2)` is much more effective and to the point.

Comment: @Ivan I see how it can be more readable to some. Why is it more `effective`?

Comment: I didn't mean in terms of speed and performance of course. What I meant was it's a bit troublesome if you have a lot of dimensions and are not looking to do any slicing on other dims at the same time you're adding that new dim. But, we can agree it does the exact same thing ;)

Comment: @FrankYellin I reverted this, because np.newaxis is just a synonym for None, which requires also to import numpy for torch, which makes no sense. Official docs use `torch.unsqueeze`

Answer (score 36):

You can add a new axis with [`torch.unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) (first argument being the index of the new axis):

```
>>> a = torch.zeros(4, 5, 6)
>>> a = a.unsqueeze(2)

>>> a.shape
torch.Size([4, 5, 1, 6])
```

Or using the in-place version: [`torch.unsqueeze_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze_):

```
>>> a = torch.zeros(4, 5, 6)
>>> a.unsqueeze_(2)

>>> a.shape
torch.Size([4, 5, 1, 6])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
```

**y will be** **->** `tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4]])`

**EDIT**: see more details here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html